# html5 kinetic text ascii

Tags: html, text, canvas, ascii, kineticjs

How to visualize ascii chars to "human readable" in kineticJS?

```
var figure = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 75/2,
        y: 75/2,
        text: "&#9816;",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: "Calibri",
        textFill: "green",
        align: "center",
        verticalAlign: "middle"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with KineticJS.  You are asking how to take a string containing HTML character entities and decode the entities.  See [Convert HTML Character Entities back to regular text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338963/convert-html-character-entities-back-to-regular-text-using-javascript) for answers to that question.