# How to convert HTML entities into special characters using plain JavaScript

Tags: html, decode, entities

With the help of bucabay we are able to encode special characters into html entities
below link for ref:
([How to convert characters to HTML entities using plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript))
Now we want to decode them i.e.how to convert HTML entities into special characters again.

Regards,
AA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML Character Entities back to regular text using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338963/convert-html-character-entities-back-to-regular-text-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the basic javascript or by using the jQuery..

newText = "Übergroße Äpfel mit Würmern";

var my_unescaped_text = jQuery('').html(newText).text();

Comment: need to convert those html entities into special characters.

Comment: This introduces a security risk in the form of a cross-site scripting vulnerability: if the input (`newText`) contains something like `<svg onload=alert(1)>`, that `alert(1)` would be executed. This solution is also dependent on the browser’s support for character references, which even in modern browsers is not perfect across the board: http://mathias.html5.org/tests/html/ It also won’t work in non-browser environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making the browser parse the text as HTML, e.g.

```
var text = "&Uuml;bergro&szlig;e &Auml;pfel mit W&uuml;rmern";
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = text;
alert(span.innerHTML); // contains the characters as decoded
```

Comment: This introduces a security risk in the form of a cross-site scripting vulnerability: if the input (`text`) contains something like `<svg onload=alert(1)>`, that `alert(1)` would be executed. This solution is also dependent on the browser’s support for character references, which even in modern browsers is not perfect across the board: http://mathias.html5.org/tests/html/ It also won’t work in non-browser environments.

Comment: @MathiasBynens, there is nothing in the question that suggests that the data comes from an external source. Quite the opposite: the data is described as being created by encoding some characters as entities.

Answer (score 0):

For a robust solution that avoids the issues in the other answers, use [**the *he* library**](http://mths.be/he). From its README:

> *he* (for “HTML entities”) is a robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript. It supports [all standardized named character references as per HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html), handles [ambiguous ampersands](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands) and other edge cases [just like a browser would](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#tokenizing-character-references), has an extensive test suite, and — contrary to many other JavaScript solutions — *he* handles astral Unicode symbols just fine. [An online demo is available.](http://mothereff.in/html-entities)

Here’s how you’d use it:

```
var html = '&Uuml;bergro&szlig;e &Auml;pfel mit W&uuml;rmern';
var decoded = he.decode(html);
// → `decoded` is now 'Übergroße Äpfel mit Würmern'
```

[See this related Stack Overflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23831239/96656) [And this one, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596964/96656)