# Avoiding character entity formation in html

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

I have this javascript.

```
var url = http://localhost:8080/temp?a=b&amp;c=2
```

I want to url to be

```
var url = http://localhost:8080/temp?a=b&c=2
```

i.e. without `&amp;`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to insert the string into an element as HTML, then grab the resulting text:

```
function deEntify(s) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = s;
  return div.textContent || div.innerText || '';
}
```

You may want to check that the input string doesn't include character sequences that can be misinterpreted.

You might also consider the accepted answer to [*Convert HTML Character Entities back to regular text using javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338963/convert-html-character-entities-back-to-regular-text-using-javascript), however there are [*about 250 entities*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) if you want to account for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
var url = http://localhost:8080/temp?a=b&amp;c=2
```

is incorrect and does not work. You need to put the string literal in quotation marks. And you must write `&` as such, since it has no special meaning in JavaScript, only in HTML (and XML). So unless the value is to be parsed as HTML, use just

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/temp?a=b&c=2'
```