# AngularJS: escaped characters in model assigned to input value

Tags: angularjs, html-entities

I have such problem: on the server I read data and use htmlentities on it, so my letters like ä are changed to the `&auml;` and I want to show this as a value of the input tag, e.g.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.name" />
```

but here instead of ä character I see escaped version of it. If I show this value using e.g.

```
<span ng-bind-html="data.name"></span>
```

everything works.

What can I do to make it works properly?

Comment: take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338963/convert-html-character-entities-back-to-regular-text-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks, I need to change it, because it use decimal representation but in my situation is used html code, but I could add all that codes to the map.

Comment: may be this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/