# How to change json_encode API format laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

code:

```
$prop_map = DB::table('jk_property_map_jpm')->select('jpm_location','jpm_longitude','jpm_latitude')->where('jpm_location','like','%'.$par2.'%')->get();
foreach($prop_map as $k)
{
    $array = array(
                    $k->jpm_location,
                    $k->jpm_latitude,
                    $k->jpm_longitude
                    );
    $data['map'] = json_encode($array);
    echo $data['map'];
}
```

API:

```
[
  "California Frazier Park 93222 15501 Nesthorn Way",
  "34.852633",
  "-119.149963"
][
  "Oakhurst,Gold Country,California,United States",
  "37.3392607",
  "-119.7114921"
][
  "Club de Golf Fonatur, San Jos\u00c3\u00a9 del Cabo, Baja California Sur, Mexico",
  "23.0522956",
  "-109.6987974"
]
```

In this code I am simply used json_encode to create an API and here I am getting unexpected output as I mention above. I want data as mention below:

```
[   
    [
      "California Frazier Park 93222 15501 Nesthorn Way",
      "34.852633",
      "-119.149963"
    ],
    [
      "Oakhurst,Gold Country,California,United States",
      "37.3392607",
      "-119.7114921"
    ],
    [
      "Club de Golf Fonatur, San Jos\u00c3\u00a9 del Cabo, Baja California Sur, Mexico",
      "23.0522956",
      "-109.6987974"
    ]
]
```

So, How can I create like this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use laravel collection mapping function to format and return your results instead of iterating via loop and echoing out

```php
$prop_map = DB::table('jk_property_map_jpm')->select('jpm_location','jpm_longitude','jpm_latitude')->where('jpm_location','like','%'.$par2.'%')->get();
$prop_map = $prop_map->map(function ($k) {
        return [
            $k->jpm_location,
            $k->jpm_latitude,
            $k->jpm_longitude, // viva trailing commas
            ];
    });
return $prop_map; // laravel automatically serializes arrays to JSON
```

Comment: Thank you @Caddy DZ. I had a problem man i.e. I put `$prop_map` in `$data` like this `$data['locations'] = $prop_map` in my view file like `{{ $location }}` then it show `&quot;` instead of  double quots ` " ` So, How can I fix them?

Comment: Tha's because Blade echo directive `{{ }}` uses `html_escape` so you would have to trim the quotes in your php code before it reaches the view i.e `trim($location, '"');`

Comment: In case of jquery what will I do @Caddy DZ

Comment: In plain JS `location.replace(/\"/g, "")`

Comment: look I am fetching like `var data =  {{ $location }}` and I am trying to replace `&quot;` with `"` but nothing happen

Comment: @omkara please refer to this SO answer for a way to decode HTML special characters back to text in Javascript https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339083/5581565

Comment: I had solved @Caddy DZ using {! $location !}. Thanks man for your kindness.

Comment: @omkara bad idea! If $location is supplied by your application users and you'd display it without sanitizing then you're vulnerable to XSS attacks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to turn your associative array into a numeric array.

Change,

```
$data['map'] = json_encode($v);
```

To,

```
$data['map'] = json_encode(array_values($v));
```

Comment: look my code once again I have changes something in my code @Script47