# Textbox.Text displays properly, but I am not getting correct Japanese characters on server code

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm able to type Japanese characters into the textbox, and it displays well. However, when I click on the Save button, I view the text property of the textbox and its value is weird, such as 'テルからイ'

This is the value being sent and stored in the database. How do I get the normal Japanese characters that's being displayed in the textbox?

Comment: its value is weird such as '&#28961;&#26009;&#24310;&#27850' .. i just realized this automatically transforms into proper japanese characters on html

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is encoding and decoding. You can go to an [online decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/decode.aspx) to see what the characters you showed really look like. So,
`&#28961;&#26009;&#24310;&#27850;`

becomes

> 無料延泊

You can do the decoding in JavaScript (before you save to the database) either using the string class in prototype or some [inbuilt JavaScript methods](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2007/06/16/url-and-html-encoding-on-the-client-javascript-to-the.aspx) or see Stack Overflow question *[How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities)*. Or you can decode on the server in C# using [Html.Decode](http://www.csharptalk.com/2009/12/using-html-decode-with-c-string.html).