# How do i unescape HTML Entities in JS? (change &lt; to <)

Tags: javascript, html

How do i unescape HTML Entities in JS?

When googling i literally saw answers with a huge switch and people rolling their own.

I'd like the string `&lt;html xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot; &gt;` to become `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >`

Comment: Accepted answer has security issues ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395954/6476044)). To avoid XSS vulnerability you should use [he library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he). 
You can see code examples in [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596964/6476044).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a div, set it's `innerHTML` and then read `innerText`

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = "&lt;html xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot; &gt;";
alert(d.innerText || d.text || d.textContent);
```

Comment: That code doesnt work but this does http://jsfiddle.net/gHHzA/

Comment: @acid - likely a cross browser issue. will update for others.

Comment: Sky Sanders: Odd, i tried it on all installed browsers (ie8, opera, safari, chrome) and it worked except for my main browser firefox 3.6. It turns out FF uses d.textContent (i found it via firebug) http://jsfiddle.net/P3DPy/1/

Comment: @acid lolz. thanks. update should work across the board now.

Comment: Just to point out, empty string is false-y, so passing '' to this would return undefined in any browser where the last expression is undefined, because it'll fall through to there when all other tests fail. The jQuery/Sizzle implementation of elem.text() is non-trivial if elem.textContent isn't supported by the browser, so a correct implementation has to either use a framework, explicitly check for empty string, or return something like this: (typeof d.textContent === 'string') ? d.textContent : (typeof d.innerText === 'string') ? d.innerText : d.text. Messy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JS implementation of a PHP function that decodes HTML entities

http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode

Note that this function also depends on:

http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table