# Escaping of attribute values using jQuery.attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using jQuery to update the `title` attribute of an element, I find that the entities (notably `&#10;`, which is the currently recommended way of adding line breaks in the `title` attribute) do not display correctly (the entity shows up as text, and is not parsed…).

For example:

```
<!-- This works fine -->
<div title="foo&#10;bar">baz</div>
```

But this:

```
<div>baz</div>
<script>
$("div").attr('title', 'foo&#10;bar'); // Escapes the &
</script>
```

Is there a way to not have jQuery escape the value? I tried using `unescape()` before `.attr()`, but it didn't work…

Comment: It also isn't necessary even in html context http://jsfiddle.net/t5DvY/1/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right; `unescape()` will not work in this case. What you can do is something similar to what is mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480757/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-js-change-lt-to).

Basically, create an empty element using jQuery, set it's HTML to the text you want in the title (`'foo&#10;bar'` in this case) and then get back the element's text.

Sounds a little complicated? It is, but this will work for any HTML entity and it's really just a one-liner. Here's the code:

```
<div>baz</div>
<script>
    var title = $('<div/>').html('foo&#10;bar').text();
    $("div").attr('title', title);
</script>
```

Or on one line:

```
$('div').attr('title', $('<div/>').html('foo&#10;bar').text());
```

Comment: This is incredible complicated, you could have just used `'foo\nbar'` in the first place. That's what the string becomes after html unescape. `htmlUnescape('foo&#10;bar') === 'foo\nbar'`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! Because this works with other entities too (everyone else just focused on the newline, which I gave as the most annoying example).

Comment: @Artefact2 you do not need to use any entities in the first place. Give me any other example. Any given entity `"&#xYYYY;"` can be replaced with `'\uYYYY'`.

Comment: @Artefact2: Haha exactly. After posting this, I thought it might be overkill for just a newline, but I like it because it works for all entities.

Comment: Furthermore, any code point reference (`&#xYYYY;`, `'\uYYYY'` ...) can be replaced with the literal character.

Comment: @Esailija Could you make your comment an answer please? `'\uYYYY'` is apparently not well known. I didn't know it. :D

Answer (score 19):

jQuery isn't escaping anything, in fact your string is literally set as the title. You can 
simply use:

```
$("div").attr('title','foo\nbar')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5DvY/

---

There seems to be a whole lot of misunderstanding what escaping means. What you are doing is completely unnecessary.

Escaping is only necessary in a context where the character would otherwise have a special meaning and you want it not to have any special meaning.

For example, in the eyes of html parser, `<` is special. You have to replace it with `&lt;` if you want to ensure it is treated as literal
`<`. Emphasis on in the eyes of **html parser**. In javascript, `<` is not special in a string in any way, thus you could
do `elem.setAttribute("title", '""><b>hi</b>')` and that's what you get, the element's title will literally be `""><b>hi</b>`.

As for html code point references, they are generally useless. You can simply use literal characters. Instead of writing `&#x2665;`, you can simply
write `♥`. Instead of writing `&#x00F6;`, you can simply write `ö`. Here's http://jsfiddle.net/fnqDn/2/.

Comment: If there is no escaping, then why the `&#10;` isn't showing up as a line break? It does when put in the attribute directly.

Comment: @Artefact2 when you put the attribute directly in html, it is interpreted by the html parser which turns the escape sequence into `'\n'`. When you set `.attr` the value is taken literally, so you use literal values. `&#10;` is html escaped and when it is unescaped it becomes the newline character `'\n'` (`0x0A`)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is golden : `Escaping is only necessary in a context ...`. There's a lot of confusion when you start reading up on the topic.

Answer (score 5):

#### This function will save you time, if you'll be doing this a lot:

```
function unescp(x){
 return $('<div/>').html(x).text();
}
$("div").attr('title',unescp('foo&#10;bar'));
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lnru/
​

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the value in a hidden element. And let jquery copy that value to the div. Im not sure if it would pass through jQuery unnoticed, but it's worth a try...