# font Awesome As Value Of Submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, font-awesome

I would like display a font awesome icon as the submit input value. I tried the following code as per this SO question [Font-awesome, input type 'submit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686007/font-awesome-input-type-submit)

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/1077/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-primary').val('&#xf0c7;');
});
```

I do not have any control over the html that is generated, therefore I can not change the `input` to a `button`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace submit button value with ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880304/replace-submit-button-value-with-ascii-character)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the [Unicode escape sequence](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode) instead:

```
$('.btn-primary').val('\uf0c7');
```

Comment: @DarrenSweeney right, thanks. Didn’t check the result carefully enough when modifying OP’s fiddle, overlooked the `;` that showed up on the button after the icon ...