# jQuery Form Plugin - HTML inside JSON respone

Tags: jquery, json, forms, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using Malsup's jQuery Form Plugin.  I'm sending the form back to be validated and trying to return a JSON response similar to this:

```
{
"complete":0,
"formText":"<div class=\"error\">...<\/div>",
"returningNumber":12345
}
```

The json object is encoded using PHP's `json_encode()` function. In the event that the form has errors in it (empty fields, invalid inputs) the `formText` variable carries the entire html of the form to the front end and is then inserted in place of the current form.

The problem is that, from what I can tell, the Form Plugin does not allow HTML to be carried inside of a JSON object.  I will only fire the success function when the data variable does not carry any HTML in it.

Is there any way around this? Am I not escaping something properly?  Any info on this problem would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could encode your HTML part using [`htmlentities()` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), and then you can decode it like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities).

Comment: Your answer did what i wanted it to do but for some reason it's still not being accepted as a valid response.  I'll explore further.  Thanks for the link!