# How to make sure that my <br> tag get read as a html and not as text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net page. On one particular page i can add comments and when i add these comments they get saved to a db. When i want new lines the "\n" tagg is automaticly displayed when i look at it in my backend code.

So now when i get back a response i want to get my comments back but i want them to have breaking spaces on those particular places where the "\n" is displayed.

I tried this in my backend code(cs):

```
Text = text.replace("\n", "<br/>")
```

the result i get:

```
my test<br/> test text new line<br/>
```

My `<br>` tags get displayed as text.

To clarify i basicly wan to achieve this:
[Why are my "<br />" tags getting converted to "&lt;br /&gt;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353718/why-are-my-br-tags-getting-converted-to-ltbr-gt)

But from the backend code in C#.

Ive been googling and haven't been able to find a answer to this.

Comment: Text is a property of which object? Is that panel or TextBox or what?

Comment: textbox, Jon answer did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.htmlstring.aspx) with your content before printing it. So your code would be like

```
var foo = new HtmlString(text.replace("\n", "<br/>"));
```

and you would print `foo`.

Comment: Thanks m8! damn my google skills need to improve, this wasn't that hard to find once you know what to search for.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ASP.NET WebForms and you are putting the text in a Label control, this is normal behaviour. The Label control html-encodes its text before rendering it.

The Literal control does not use html-encoding, so if you change your Label to a Literal, it should work.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, try using `@Html.Raw(Model.Text)`.

Comment: thanks! was actually thinking of doing the same using a lable later on so you probably saved me some time here.