# any javascript buildin function to convert html entity to pass from url

Tags: javascript, replace, html-entities, urldecode

i have a value

```
abc&#125;efg
```

i need it to pass from URL

```
in HTML &#125; = }  
in URL &#125; = %7D
```

how to convert `&#125;` to `%7D`?

Answer (score 1):

[`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) combined with [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities).

jQuery's [`.html()`](http://api.jQuery.com/html) function is basically a thin function wrapper around the [widely-supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03) (vanilla DOM) [`innerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML), so the linked question is still applicable if you're not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The function was named **encodeURIComponent**, and fortunately it's a built-in funciton. You can use it for free:

```
alert( encodeURIComponent("}") ) //-- alert box will show "%7D"
```

Comment: Sure - but that doesn't address the problem of the HTML entity. You need to deal with 'encodeURIComponent("&#125")' first

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to:

1. Decode the URI component
2. Encode the ASCII component to an HTML entity

So, first of all, I'd recommend an Entity dictionary like this excellent one:
http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js

This should help you out from there:

```
function browerURLtoEntity( code ) {
    var crypt = {};
        crypt.URI = code;
        crypt.ascii = decodeURLComponent(crypt.URI);
        crypt.entity = Encoder.htmlEncode(crypt.ascii);
    return crypt;
}
// crypt.entity will be the piece that you want.
```