# Convert a string containing HTML entities to uppercase

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how can I convert a string containing HTML entities to uppercase. Take the string 'Cafés & Bars' for example:

`Caf&eacute;s &amp; Bars`

It needs to be converted to:

`CAF&Eacute;S &amp; BARS`

If `toUpperCase()` were used, it would destroy both the entities. If the text were to be uppercased and then text between `&` and `;` were lowercased then the acute E would remain lowercase.

In my particular case, I am unable to solve this using the `text-transform: uppercase` style.

Comment: Decode the entities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function decodeEntities(string){
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = string;
return elem.textContent;
}
```

Then simply do something like `decodeEntities('Caf&eacute;s &amp; Bars').toUpperCase();`
But note that when you do, your returned text won't be `CAF&Eacute;S &amp; BARS` it will be CAFÉS & BARS

Comment: you way is much nicer than my version

Comment: @david Thank you. It's good that you're providing for browser incompatibilities by using textContent or innerText, depending on which is available. Note that you don't actually need to append the element or give it an id. Just create it, give it its innerHTML to decode and get its value back from the reference of the created element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping there's enough examples in this fiddle to solve things for you. FYI, you don't mention if you are using jQuery or not, I can update this if you need just vanilla JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/hafichuk/APNWh/

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the text representation, you can use (or convert text-named entities to) decimal HTML entities; they don't get converted to uppercase, because numbers have only one case.

So:

Instead of `&amp;` use `&#38;`
Instead of `&lt;` use `&#60`
Instead of `&quot;` use `&#34;`

etc.