# Given a string with HTML entities, how to decode the HTML entities?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like so:

```
var x = "as dsa sad asd &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;asd asd asd asd asd asd asd"
```

How can I decode that string to get just:

```
"as dsa sad asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd"
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd be curious to know where the string comes from and then were it is being sent. You may not need to do any decoding depending on your use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery decode HTML entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities).

Comment: It's in a contenteditable div

Comment: var decoded = $("<div/>").html(encodedStr).text();


- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities/2419664#2419664

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var encoded = "as dsa sad asd &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;asd asd asd asd asd asd asd";
alert(encoded);
var decoded = $('<textarea />').html(encoded).val();
alert(decoded);
```

or

```
var decoded = $("<div/>").html(encoded).text();
```