# Regular Expression - Need help on getting specific part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the stantard string structure:

```
{&quot;actor&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;target_fbid&quot;:&quot;286108458103936&quot;,&quot;target_profile_id&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;type_id&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;assoc_obj_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;source_app_id&quot;:&quot;2305272732&quot;,&quot;extra_story_params&quot;:[],&quot;content_timestamp&quot;:&quot;1325711938&quot;,&quot;check_hash&quot;:&quot;892251599922cc58&quot;}
```

the only part i need from this string is the numeric value after the "target_profile_id", in this case, would be "100003221104984"

I really suck at regular expressions and any help would be really appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your string really have all those `&quot;`s in it, or are those supposed to be `"`s?

Comment: `(?<=&quot;actor&quot;:&quot;)\d+(?=&quot;)` is the regex you want. http://regexr.com?2vl57

Answer (score 2):

The data appears to be in JSON format (minus HTML escaped). As such, there is no need for a regular expression.

Instead, access it directly:

```
var data = {"actor":"100003221104984","target_fbid":"286108458103936", ...}
alert(data.target_profile_id);
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZtR2/).

#### UPDATE

As noted by **Jonathan**, if the string indeed includes HTML entities, you will need to first parse it to create an object to assign to `data` in my example above.

There are additional posts on SO that answer how to do that. For example: [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities)

Comment: If that is stored in a string like the question suggests it will first need to be parsed to safely create an object. See http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @Jonathan, indeed. As I noted, the string is ultimately JSON and can be access as shown in my example. I will update with your note for completeness though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all these &quo te; stuff you could also do it by getting the right chars, without regex

```
var x = 
"{&quot;actor&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;target_fbid&quot;:&quot;286108458103936&quot;,&quot;target_profile_id&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;type_id&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;assoc_obj_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;source_app_id&quot;:&quot;2305272732&quot;,&quot;extra_story_params&quot;:[],&quot;content_timestamp&quot;:&quot;1325711938&quot;,&quot;check_hash&quot;:&quot;892251599922cc58&quot;}";

var begin = x.indexOf("target_profile_id")+ "target_profile_id".length + "&quot;:&quot;".length;
var endString = x.substring(begin, x.length);
var end = endString.indexOf("&quot;") + begin;
alert(x.substring(begin, end));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[`/&quot;actor&quot;:&quot;(\[^&\]+)/`](http://www.rubular.com/r/gIqR05UNi1)

or

[`/"actor":"([^&]+)/`](http://www.rubular.com/r/0XobNJpp49)

Answer (score 0):

I have understood your problem. The whole string is actually a JSON object, where quote(") is present in the form of &quot ;.

First replace & quote; it with ". Then evaluate the expression and get the value of any item you want.

Below working code :)

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
var str1="{&quot;actor&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;target_fbid&quot;:&quot;286108458103936&quot;,&quot;target_profile_id&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;type_id&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;assoc_obj_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;source_app_id&quot;:&quot;2305272732&quot;,&quot;extra_story_params&quot;:[],&quot;content_ti&quot;:{&quot;actor&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;target_fbid&quot;:&quot;286108458103936&quot;,&quot;target_profile_id&quot;:&quot;100003221104984&quot;,&quot;type_id&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;assoc_obj_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;source_app_id&quot;:&quot;2305272732&quot;,&quot;extra_story_params&quot;:[],&quot;content_timestamp&quot;:&quot;1325711938&quot;,&quot;check_hash&quot;:&quot;892251599922cc58&quot;}}";
var ans=str1.split("&quot;").join("\"");
var obj=eval("(" + ans+ ')');
alert(obj.target_profile_id);
</script>
```

And see how your actual Data looks like:

```
{
    "actor": "100003221104984",
    "target_fbid": "286108458103936",
    "target_profile_id": "100003221104984",
    "type_id": "17",
    "source": "1",
    "assoc_obj_id": "",
    "source_app_id": "2305272732",
    "extra_story_params": [],
    "content_ti": {
        "actor": "100003221104984",
        "target_fbid": "286108458103936",
        "target_profile_id": "100003221104984",
        "type_id": "17",
        "source": "1",
        "assoc_obj_id": "",
        "source_app_id": "2305272732",
        "extra_story_params": [],
        "content_timestamp": "1325711938",
        "check_hash": "892251599922cc58"
    }
}
```