# Javascript decoding html entities

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

I want to convert this text:

```
"&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
```

to html, with tags and everything in Javascript or Jquery. How to do this?

Comment: your final export: <p>name</p><p><span style="font-size:xx-small;">ajde</span></p><p><em>da</em></p></body>

Comment: Easiest way is to assign a class selector to your element and then use this code
`$('.selector').each(function(a,b){$(b).html($(b).text())})`

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
var text = '&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
var decoded = $('<textarea/>').html(text).text();
alert(decoded);
```

This sets the innerHTML of a new  element (not appended to the page), causing jQuery to decode it into HTML, which is then pulled back out with .text().

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aZxjG/).

Comment: What if the text is `"><img src=x onerror=prompt(1)>`?

Comment: don't use `$('<div/>')` - i't make posible XSS atack. Use `$('<textarea/>');`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is also proper (I'm using jQuery 2.x): `$.parseHTML(text)[0].textContent;`

Comment: When encoded string contains *Enter* sign between tags, this returns just *Enter* instead of html (at least in Chrome). to fix it I changed solution to `$('<textarea/>').html(text).html()`

Comment: It's a very bad idea because is allowing HTML injection.
for example if in the incoming text you have something like this:
`<script>alert(code injection')</script>`
it will show an alert on the user screen.

Comment: that's why you have to sanitize the text first `<script>` will become `&lt;script&gt;` when sanitized and when applied to above code, it will be back to `<script>` but as a text

Answer (score 18):

There is a jQuery solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery). Try something like this:

```
var decoded = $("<div/>").html('your string').text();
```

This sets the innerHTML of a new `<div>` element (not appended to the page), causing jQuery to decode it into HTML, which is then pulled back out with `.text()`.

Comment: not working in firefox

Answer (score 11):

Using jQuery the easiest will be:

```
var text = '&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';

var output = $("<div />").html(text).text();
console.log(output);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LKGZx/

Comment: Same as the other two answers. You'll get a badge of honor if you delete the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this ?

```
$('#your_id').html('&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;').text();
```