# Encode HTML entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encode, html-entities

I am parsing some data from feedburner of which contains HTML entities. I am trying to encode the HTML entities using jQuery as such:

```
var encodedStr = data['1']['result']['content']; // content with HTML entities
$("#content").html(encodedStr).text();
```

but with no results.

Here is what its parsed: http://jsbin.com/ihadam/1/edit

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This is unclear.

Comment: Do you want to interpret the `&lt;p&gt;` stuff as actual HTML tags when you insert it?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Check this: http://jsbin.com/ihadam/2/edit - I want it to be an actual image tag rather than a string.

Comment: I think this might do what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities

Comment: @TravisSharp It's exactly what I said I have tried of which doesn't work.

Comment: I use [_.escape()](http://underscorejs.org/#escape) for this.

Comment: @jgillich It wouldn't work as _.escape() uses the same method of what I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should encode your html entities into html as such:

```
var encodedStr = data['1']['result']['content'];
var a = $("#content").html(encodedStr).text();
```

Then get the encoded text and apply it as html() as such:

```
$("#content").html(a);
```

That should work.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ihadam/9/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can save the bloat of JQuery with pure JavaScript functions.

Sometimes you just want to encode every character... This function replaces "everything except for nothing" in regxp.

```
function encode(e){return e.replace(/[^]/g,function(e){return"&#"+e.charCodeAt(0)+";"})}
```

```js
function encode(w) {
  return w.replace(/[^]/g, function(w) {
    return "&#" + w.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
  });
}

test.value=encode(document.body.innerHTML.trim());
```

```html
<textarea id=test rows=11 cols=55>www.WHAK.com</textarea>
```