# How to replace < and > with &lt; and &gt; with jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching for a day or so how to do something with JS or jQuery and found a couple of solutions but nothing solid yet.

I want to use this:

```
<code class="codeIt">

  <h2> This is an H2 </h2>

</code>
```

And I want the output to be:

`<h2> This is an H2 </h2>`

I know I can achieve this by doing:

```
<code class="codeIt">

  &lt;h2&gt; This is an H2 &lt;/h2&gt;

</code>
```

...But I would like to not do a manual search and replace on my code in those blocks and rather have it done on the fly in the browser. Is this possible?

I'm pretty noob with jQuery so I've tried `.replaceWith` or JavaScript's `.replace` but so far I've not gotten where I need to be with it. I'm either replacing the whole tag or doing something else wrong.

My question is: How would I write a simple jQuery (or regular JS) to help me replace my `<` and my `>` with HTML entities like `&lt;` and `&gt;` inside my `<code>` tags.

I appreciate any help, Thanks.

## UPDATE:

I managed to get it working nice how @Prisoner explained, it's very nifty, however this in my particular case needed a little extending because I have more than one block of code with the `.codeIt` class, so I had to make it check each element and output... otherwise it would keep making the same output (like the first block)

### [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/T5jGe/)

Thanks to everyone for their answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode HTML entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713449/encode-html-entities)

Comment: use escape character with them

Comment: &#60; for  <  and 
&#62; for  >    use can use these

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12034334/1073758

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you just want to escape all HTML:

```
$(".codeIt").text($(".codeIt").html());
```

Comment: If you run that code on this page (changing selector to just "code" of course), it fails quite spectacularly

Comment: This seems like the solution I'm looking for definitively, however, it's just not working for me, it keeps rendering the `<h2>` as a heading an not as text. What could I be possibly doing wrong by implementing one line of code? hehe... I know I have the selector right. I tried it with a `<code>` tag or a `<div>` tag and no go.

Comment: @sulfureous, it must be your inclusion of jQuery or the way you're running the code. This basic example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/T8kBt/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work now. Must have been a cache issue.

Answer (score 5):

Plain JS for single `code` element

```
var myCode = document.getElementById('mycode');
myCode.innerHTML = myCode.innerHTML.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
```

Plain JS for multiple `code` elements

```
var codeEls = document.getElementsByTagName('code');
for(var i in codeEls)
{
    if(parseInt(i)==i)
    {
        var codeEl = codeEls[i];
        if(codeEl.className.match(/\bcodeIt\b/)!==null) codeEl.innerHTML = codeEl.innerHTML.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
    }
}
```

or jQuery

```
$(".codeIt").each(function() {
    $(this).html(
        $(this).html().replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the text function of jquery:

```
var myText = $('.codeIt').html();

var escapedText = $('.codeIt').text(myText).html();
```

Comment: Thank you @harpax this definitively works too, but it's longer than the accepted answer and it does the same... But it works, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = $('.codeIt').html();

$('.codeIt').text(t).html();
```

Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kU8bV/1/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't link to your fiddle, it just links to jsfiddle.net

Comment: This worked for me as in the fiddle. It's simple and it makes sense now, so we are creating a variable called `t` and it equals to the HTML of the `.codeIt` element and then we are taking that same `.codeIt` element and using the `.text()` method to print the `t` variable as text and add it to the HTML. Am I understanding this right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('code').html($('code').html().replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'));
```

Comment: This will only replace the first instance of `<` and `>`. You need to do a global regexp replace, like @SmokeyPHP.

Comment: Please include a description of your solution for it to be a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to code all the html in codeIt class :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function htmlEncode(value){
            if (value) {
                return jQuery('<div />').text(value).html();
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        function htmlDecode(value) {
            if (value) {
                return $('<div />').html(value).text();
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }       
        $('.codeIt').each(function() {
            myEncodedString = htmlEncode($(this).html());
            $(this).html(myEncodedString);
        });
</script>
```