# Javascript var with specialchars with AJAX to $_GET in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get, special-characters

I have a text form with CKEditor:

```
<textarea id="descrizione_it"></textarea>
<textarea id="descrizione_fr"></textarea>
... many others inputs ...    
<button onclick="addDataProd()">
```

The JS Function:

```
function addDataProd(){
    var descrizione_it = CKEDITOR.instances.descrizione_it.getData()
    var descrizione_fr = CKEDITOR.instances.descrizione_fr.getData()

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();     
    } else {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }

xmlhttp.open("GET","prodotti_ajax.php?descrizione_it_new="+descrizione_it + "&descrizione_fr_new="+descrizione_fr,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And the PHP with get the data and updates the database.

Now if I wrote some special charaters on the CKEditor textarea, those charaters are always and immediatly converted tu htmlentities (è).

If I write on the JS

```
alert(descrizione_fr)
```

I get the string as written in CKEditor e.g.

èèèà

but when I echo the string in php the string stops just before the special charaters.

E.g. JS:

```
alert(descrizione_fr)
```

results in:

```
test_test_&egrave;test
```

PHP:

```
echo $_GET['descrizione_fr_new'];
```

results in:

```
test_test_
```

How can I solve that?

Thank you!

Comment: encodeURIComponent(var) is the right way?

Comment: When it comes to textareas (CKEditor), it's better to POST the data, rather than use GET.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function that use the browser parser to do it.
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/wfuTy/1/)

```
function html_decode(text){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = text;
    return ("textContent" in div) ? div.textContent : div.innerText ;
}
```

I don't know if it's the best way. But I found [this solution in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities) and made it pure javascript.
Hope it help

**EDIT**: using textContent(IE9+) as default and innerText as fallback for compatibility

Comment: Thank you. With encodeURIComponent(var_to_encode) I get the same results... Maybe it's better to use this?

Comment: I'm thinking about `innerText` property.. I don't know if Firefox recognize it.. but there's `textContent` too..

Comment: This just solve your html encode/decode problem.. 
Use it on your `alert(descrizione_fr)` like `alert(html_decode(descrizione_fr))`..
Use it only if you know the content, it will parse script tags as well..