# jquery parseHTML not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing, jsonp

I'm getting json data back from a jsonp call. The data is coming back alright. One data element is in the form of a string with some html in it ("p" tag, "a" tag). I'm trying to output this element (a picture description) within a jQuery dialog box. For some reason I can't get it to render as html, whether I use $.parseHTML or not.

Code snippet:

```
var image       = data.image;
var title       = data.title;
var id          = data.id;
var description = $.parseHTML( data.description );
var media       = data.media;
var secret      = data.secret;
if(media == "photo"){
    var string  = "<div id=\"picturebox\" class=\"picturebox\">\n";
    string += "    <img src=\""+image + "\" id=\"photo_"+id+"\" />\n";
    string += "    <h2>" + title + "</h2>\n";
    string += "    <p>" + description + "</p>\n";
    string += "</div>\n";
    $('#gbFullPic').html(string);
}
```

Although the dynamically produced div correctly displays, including the image and title, the "description" line outputs like this:
    [object Text]

If I remove the $.parseHTML the output looks like this:

```
Bird of paradise growing in south Florida.<p><a href="http://www.popgnology.com/guestbook.php">ACME Adventures</a></p>
```

That would be alright of course, if my html output did not show the actual html tags. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE (2nd revision):
My previous solution was incomplete. The problem was more complicated than a single jquery or javascript solution.

The problem began on the server side, with badly formed html that was sent via

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $cid . '('.json_encode($data).')';
```

- On the server side (PHP), I had to condition my "description" item, like so (note the addition of htmlspecialchars_decode and an addslashes wrapper):

  ```
    if($k == "description"){ 
      $data["$k"] = addslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($v));
    }
    else{
      $data["$k"] = $v;
    }
  ```
- Then, this javascript properly rendered the json data item:

  ```
  var description   = data.description.replace('\\','');
  ```

With that two-step process of correcting the delivery format on the server page, and stripping slashes using a .replace on the client side, the "description" properly displays all text and html elements on the html page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your data.description is escaped and the method parseHTML isn't going to handle that. Check out this post for a solution:

[Javascript decoding html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities)

```
var text = '&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(text).text();
alert(decoded);
```

So in your case:

```
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(data.description).text();
$('#gbFullPic').html(decoded);
```

Comment: Thanks Loud. With a little fiddling around, I applied your principles to my problem and now it works. I'll edit my question to display the new code.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. It was exactly what you stated for me, but it was a problem with needing to change double quotes to single quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Try `var description = $($.parseHTML(data.description)).html();`

jQuery's [parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) returns an array of DOM nodes. You could then insert them into the DOM, but in your case you should get their [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and add it to your string.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but using that gives me: Error: TypeError: $.parseHTML(...).html is not a function

Comment: the same "TypeError: jQuery.parseHtml is not a function" when try to use $.parseHtml() what can it be?

Comment: @user1954544 - `$.parseHTML` should be a function if jQuery is loaded properly, I did realise just now when looking at it that my answer contained an error, I had forgotten to wrap the `parseHTML` output in a jQuery object (which is the source of the `TypeError: $.parseHTML(...).html is not a function` error, I've just fixed it in the answer.