# jQuery parse htmlspecialchars() string as text

Tags: php, jquery, htmlspecialchars

I've run into an issue.  I am building an Ajax application with PHP, and am sanitizing my inputs via htmlspecialchars().  I am then processing the inputted string and using that to set the data attributes of certain html elements.  There's my problem.

Let's just say the user wrote `<html>`.  That input, with htmlspecialchars(), would be turned into `&lt;html&gt;`.  Now this is fine for **displaying** the content, but for the data attributes, I would like it to be inserted as `<html>`.  Is this possible?

Comment: What are you going to do with the data attributes?

Comment: The user inputs a string, I break down the string, and use the data attributes to search the string.

Comment: The thing is, you *could* of course refrain from using htmlspecialchars() for that specific case but then you would be nullifying the security that you're using the sanitation for in the first place - you could then just as well stop using it at all on that page. That's probably not a good idea. How are you searching the string, maybe you can convert the special characters back at that point?

Comment: Well, I am using a button with the data attributes.  So would it be possible to set the data with non-escaped html, and set the physical html of the button with the escaped html?

Comment: Yes, so what I'm saying is set the data attributes with non-escaped html, and set the inner html of the button with the escaped html.

Comment: It's fine to use `htmlspecialchars()` for attributes. The browser should decode them when processing the attribute strings.

Comment: Got it.  Let me try this and I'll tell you what happens.

Comment: Note that you only need to use `htmlspecialchars()` at all if PHP is creating the HTML. You don't need to use it when passing data back and forth using AJAX.

Comment: So I do have php creating the data attributes.  Would I have to use it on those data attributes?

Comment: So then my plan above wouldn't work, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the situation, so I don't know. Either way, you could do the decoding (if necessary) in JavaScript: [Javascript decoding html entities](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10715801)

Comment: Actually, I just found a solution by creating two different variables based on the same input, one totally stripped of all non-alphabetic characters and one sanitized via htmlspecialchars()

Answer (score 0):

there is a function that reverses what htmlspecialchars does:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Well no, xss vulnerability