# Changin JSON back to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am storing innerHTML of each element in javascript object in JSON format. How can I get HTML back from this object?

The object looks like that.

```
content[0]: "&quot;&lt;div class=&quot;editor ui-resizable ui-draggable&quot; contenteditable=&quot;true&quot; style=&quot;position: absolute; left: 345.10072326660156px; top: 339.10418701171875px;&quot;&gt;&lt;h2 class=&quot;text2&quot;&gt;Tikkkkkke&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 90;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 90;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 90;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-trash2 icon-on-edit&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_trash.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;icon-move icon-on-edit&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;icon-font font2 icon-on-edit&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-font-size icon-on-edit&quot; src=&quot;/assets/font_size2.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ui-wrapper ui-draggable&quot; style=&quot;overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 223px; height: 198px; top: 103.22222900390625px; left: 278.2222442626953px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;img id=&quot;link-2&quot; style=&quot;position: static; margin: 0px; resize: none; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 198px; width: 223px;&quot; src=&quot;http://i.imgur.com/sTxNVlo.png &quot; class=&quot;ui-resizable&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 90;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 90;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 90;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-layer-up icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_layer_up.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-layer-down icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_layer_down.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-trash1 icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_trash.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-copy-el icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_copy.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-layer-up icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_layer_up.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-layer-down icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_layer_down.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-trash1 icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_trash.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-copy-el icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_copy.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-layer-up icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_layer_up.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-layer-down icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_layer_down.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-trash1 icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_trash.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;icon-copy-el icon-on-img&quot; src=&quot;/assets/icon_copy.png&quot; style=&quot;z-index: 2;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;↵  ↵       ↵    ↵     ↵          ↵  ↵       ↵    ↵     ↵          ↵  ↵       ↵    ↵     ↵          ↵  ↵       ↵    ↵     ↵          ↵  ↵       ↵    ↵     ↵          ↵                    ↵         ↵    ↵        ↵      ↵      ↵      ↵      ↵      ↵      ↵      &quot;"
```

I am trying to get HTML from this like that:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("preview");
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    var stepWrapper = y.document.querySelectorAll(".step-wrapper");
    var contentObject = $("#data-store").data();
    if (contentObject["content[0]"] !== undefined) {
       for (var i = 0; i < stepWrapper.length; i++) {
          stepWrapper[i].innerHTML = contentObject["content[" + i + "]"];
       }
    }
```

but it prints JSON inside stepWrapper div and prints text :

```
" <div class="editor ui-resizable ui-draggable" contenteditable="true" style="position: absolute; left: 345.10072326660156px; top: 339.10418701171875px;"><h2 class="text2">Tikkkkkke</h2><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;">..
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could make your JSON object more readable.

Comment: You have to decode HTML entities. And Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities