# Decode HTML entity in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-entities, utf8-decode

How do i decode HTML entity in text using angular JS.

I have the string

```
"&quot;12.10 On-Going Submission of &quot;&quot;Made Up&quot;&quot; Samples.&quot;"
```

I need a way to decode this using Angular JS. I found a way to do that using javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities) but I am sure thats wont work for Angular. Need to get back the original string on the UI which would look like

```
""12.10 On-Going Submission of ""Made Up"" Samples.""
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the **[`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)** directive to display it as an html content with all the html entities decoded. Just make sure to include the **[`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)** dependency in your application.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Axg7NJvQKJl3rBkEwdRZ?p=preview)**

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])

  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.html = '&quot;12.10 On-Going Submission of &quot;&quot;Made Up&quot;&quot; Samples.&quot;';
  });
```

*HTML*

```
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: but if you dont wont to rendered it as html , how you can deal with it ?

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to use ngSanitize, you can do it this way:

in your controller:

```
$scope.html = '&quot;12.10 On-Going Submission of &quot;&quot;Made Up&quot;&quot; Samples.&quot;'
$scope.renderHTML = function(html_code)
        {
            var decoded = angular.element('<textarea />').html(html_code).text();
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(decoded);
        };
```

And in the template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHTML(html)"></div>
```

Just make sure you inject $sce in your controller

Comment: This works but I get this error in the console:

`angular.min.js:123 TypeError: angular.element(...).html(...).text is not a function
    at b.$scope.renderHTML (app.js:24)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:239), <anonymous>:4:284)
    at angular.min.js:129
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:146)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:149)
    at angular.min.js:21
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:44)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at Sc (angular.min.js:22)
    at ue (angular.min.js:20)`

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue, but don't need to use result value on UI. This issue was resolved by code from angular ngSanitize module:

```js
var hiddenPre=document.createElement("pre");
/**
* decodes all entities into regular string
* @param value
* @returns {string} A string with decoded entities.
*/
function decodeEntities(value) {
  if (!value) { return ''; }
    
  hiddenPre.innerHTML = value.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
  // innerText depends on styling as it doesn't display hidden elements.
  // Therefore, it's better to use textContent not to cause unnecessary reflows.
  return hiddenPre.textContent;
}


var encoded = '&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
var decoded = decodeEntities(encoded);

document.getElementById("encoded").innerText=encoded;
document.getElementById("decoded").innerText=decoded;
```

```css
#encoded {
  color: green;
}

#decoded {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Encoded: <br/>
<div id="encoded">
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

Decoded: <br/>
<div id="decoded">
</div>
```