# Angular: HTML decoding and encoding in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In our Angular app we are using an pi that returns strings containing HTML encoded characters, for example it would return `'let&#39;s'` where `&#39;` is the encoded "single quote character"

I would like to create a function htmlDecode(myString) to return the decoded string in the javascript code, for example:

```
var myString = 'let&#39;s';
var decodedString = htmlDecode(myString);
console.log(decodedString);               // CONSOLE OUTPUT: "let's"
```

I looked at the `$sce` service but could not come up with a solution yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Entity Decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entity in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064309/decode-html-entity-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to set the innerHTML and read the text

```
function htmlDecode (str) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = str;
    return div.textContent || div.innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this item:
[ngModel Formatters and Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers)

Just use $formatters to change the model value.