# angularJS & php- HTML tags not getting decoded

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, html

I'm building a new project in angularJS. Backend is PHP with MySQL. PHP API returns data to angular which I need to show in front view.

But HTML tags are not getting decoded in my website. Thay are shown as such. When I try the same in phpfiddle.org, it works.

User submits data through a wysiwyg editor and it is saved in database table something like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;dfgdfgdfgfd&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;dg&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;d&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;g&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644203224_7186990890070339&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;df&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644203224_09491296280590866&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644197601_045958185758413816&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;g&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644197601_8700155449427347&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Following is the method I used to decode HTML in PHP before it returns the data to front end.

```
<?php
$valueFromDB= "&lt;p&gt;dfgdfgdfgfd&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;dg&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;d&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;g&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644203224_7186990890070339&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;df&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644203224_09491296280590866&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644197601_045958185758413816&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;g&lt;span class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot; id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1472644197601_8700155449427347&quot;&gt;&amp;#65279;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;";

$decoded =  html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($valueFromDB,ENT_QUOTES));

echo $decoded;
?>
```

It works in fiddle but in real website, this is how it looks.

[image]

Why it's not working in website when it works in a fiddle?

Comment: don't use angular template expression (e.g. {{}}). use **ng-bind-html** attribute

Comment: i found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064309/decode-html-entity-in-angular-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are trying to print the query result using angular's $http, then try using ng-bind-html

```
<div ng-bind-html="queryResult"></div>
```

this directive requires angular-sanitize.