# html code is not getting decoded with linky

Tags: angularjs

I have text `$scope.post.details = &lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;`

I have this directive:

```
var app = angular.module('mobApp.services');
app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.compile, function(html) {
            element.html(html);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
    };
}]);
```

I am using like

problem is `&lt;b&gt;` is not getting render as `<b>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entity in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064309/decode-html-entity-in-angular-js)

Comment: thats not my solution

Answer (score 1):

Well I have a JavaScript function that converts string to HTML. You could use this function to convert it into HTML

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```