# Foreign letters failing when sending emails

Tags: javascript, email, letters

I sometimes have to send emails in a German and I need to use ö ä ß etc... I have text written containing these letter and using alert() they appear just fine. I have code to send an email :

```
    var link = "mailto:" + SendTo
         + "&cc= " 
         + "&subject=" + escape(subjectLine)
         + "&body=" + escape(BodyText);
         window.location.href = link;
```

When I click a button to send the email, the text is missing these foreign letters e.g gruß comes out as gru. Do I need to put anything in here to make sure these letter don't disappear?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The **deprecated** escape() method computes a new string in which certain characters have been replaced by a hexadecimal escape sequence. Use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent instead.

Comment: Thank you MrUpsidown
works like a dream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following articles shows how to decode the letters using javascript :

[Javascript decoding html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities)

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```

[HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Using jquery:

```
varTitle = $('<textarea />').html("Chris&apos; corner").text();
```