# Showing Special Characters in Confirm Box

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have code to show confirm box on clicking on Close Button. 
And it should show a message along with the name of the month. The month names are in German, and German has special characters for some months like *March - März*.

The confirm box is not showing the speical characters.
Can anyone please help me?

**My code:**

```
 function chk_abschliessen()
 {
      var chk = confirm("Möchten Sie diesen Stundenzettel wirklich abschliessen?\nStundenzettel " + '@Model.monat.datum.Value.ToString("MMMM")' + " " + '@Model.monat.datum.Value.Year' + " ");

      if (chk)
      {              
           document.closebutton.submit()                
      }
      else
      {
           return false;
      }
 }
```

The confirm box shows:

> Möchten Sie diesen Stundenzettel wirklich abschliessen? Stundenzettel M&#228;rz 2016

I used a temporary solution, posting it here, as it might help someone else --

```
function clear_amp(data)
    {
        // for month "März"
        var ret = data.replace("&#228;", "ä");

        return ret;
    }

    //Abschliessen Messages Check - BEGIN

    function chk_abschliessen()
    {
        var chk = confirm("Möchten Sie diesen Stundenzettel wirklich abschliessen?\nStundenzettel " + clear_amp('@Model.monat.datum.Value.ToString("MMMM")') + " " + '@Model.monat.datum.Value.Year' + " ");
        if (chk)
        { 
          document.closebutton.submit()                
        }
        else
       {
       return false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: It may also be useful to see what the rendered output is to make sure it hasn't mangled the model values while writing the javascript.

Comment: The `@Model` in your code indicates that this is a .cshtml Razor page. Do special characters show correctly if you have them in the HTML of the page? Do special characters show correctly if you invoke a `confirm` from a separate JavaScript file?

Comment: So it's HTML encoding it where it shouldn't be then.  I haven't used razor enough to give a definitive answer, but I _think_ `@Html.Raw` may help here.

Comment: I used a temporary solution, posting it here, as it might help someone else.

Comment: Please look to my answer, please mark it if it is suitable for you

Comment: Well, the proposed solution is not flexible enough for different letters, please see my solution below it will be work for any German letter. cheers !

Answer (score 0):

So it should display **März** instead of `M&#228;rz`

Actually the JavaScript decodeURIComponent() function is used to decode the characters in the url-specific charactuers.

In your case it is Html encoded, so you can encode/decode the string using HtmlDecode/HtmlEncode functions as following :

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model.monat.datum.Value.ToString("MMMM"))
```

Also take a look to this article [WebUtility.HtmlDecode vs HttpUtilty.HtmlDecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352981/webutility-htmldecode-vs-httputilty-htmldecode)

This link contains the html characture for the german language

http://character-code.com/german-html-codes.php

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem with email output and was advised to use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() in my code with this issue [Foreign letters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005855/foreign-letters-failing-when-sending-emails).

Comment: Try running `confirm(encodeURIComponent('ä'))`.  URI component encoding is not a suitable solution for encoding here.