# Javascript decoding special charcters

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, escaping, decode

I'm receiving from my server a string with `"` char as `&quot;`.
I would like to display this string correctly without any coded characters

So I try to use decodeURI or unescape function as follows:

```
decodeURI("&quot;")
unescape("&quot;")
```

buy still the output stays coded

```
"&quot;"
```

Any clue why?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're able to use jquey, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode) have already been answered.

Comment: Im locking for a javascript solution since i want to store this values in variable.
I using angularJs so i would like the code to look like this:

var dataFromServer = &quot;";
$scope.dataToDisplay = decodingFunction(dataFromServer);

The question is what could be the decodingFunction?

Answer (score 0):

`decodeURI()` and `unescape()` are used to decode URI content, not HTML. 
I think you are mixing your technologies.

If jquery is available then these might help you:
[Javascript decoding html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities)
[How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery

```
$("myel").html("&quot;");
```

will result as proper string on the screen, while the source is  "\

Answer (score 0):

If you want the javascript-only version to decode that, use this:

```
function decodingFunctionVer(str) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("div");
    tmp.innerHTML = str;
    return tmp.textContent;
}
```

With [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxbcntk2/1/) demo.

Comment: Funny we wrote exacly the same sulotion simutansly! :)

Comment: Yep, saw your reply when in a subway, got to get home for code :P

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
function decodeText(encodedText){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = encodedText;
        var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
        return decoded;
    }
```

I don't like this solution becuse it includes creating a redundent element but it works.

Thanks for the help