# Double quote gets replaced by &quote;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JavaScript variable contains a string:

```
{"start":{"lat":19.0759842,"lng":72.87765630000001},"end":{"lat":18.5206624,"lng":73.8567415},"waypoints":[[18.8753235,73.52948409999999]]}
```

But when I show it into HTML component, it looks like:

```
{&quot;start&quot;:{&quot;lat&quot;:19.0759842,&quot;lng&quot;:72.87765630000001},&quot;end&quot;:{&quot;lat&quot;:18.5206624,&quot;lng&quot;:73.8567415},&quot;waypoints&quot;:[[18.8753235,73.52948409999999]]}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities

Comment: Double  quotation get convert to &quot;. this is problem

Answer (score 5):

Output the string as HTML instead of plain text so the HTML entity `&quot;` is rendered correctly.

```js
var s = "{&quot;start&quot;:{&quot;lat&quot;:19.0759842,&quot;lng&quot;:72.87765630000001},&quot;end&quot;:{&quot;lat&quot;:18.5206624,&quot;lng&quot;:73.8567415},&quot;waypoints&quot;:[[18.8753235,73.52948409999999]]}";

//Incorrect with jQuery
$("#incorrect-jquery").text(s);

//Correct with jQuery
$("#correct-jquery").html(s);

//Incorrect with plain JavaScript
document.getElementById("incorrect-js").textContent = s;

//Correct with plain JavaScript
document.getElementById("correct-js").innerHTML = s;
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<strong>Incorrect with jQuery</strong>
<div id="incorrect-jquery"></div>

<strong>Correct with jQuery</strong>
<div id="correct-jquery"></div>

<strong>Incorrect with plain JavaScript</strong>
<div id="incorrect-js"></div>

<strong>Correct with plain JavaScript</strong>
<div id="correct-js"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var text1 = '{&quot;start&quot;:{&quot;lat&quot;:19.0759842,&quot;lng&quot;:72.87765630000001},&quot;end&quot;:{&quot;lat&quot;:18.5206624,&quot;lng&quot;:73.8567415},&quot;waypoints&quot;:[[18.8753235,73.52948409999999]]}';
var text2 = text1.replace(/&quot;/g, '\"');

alert('Your data\n' + text1);

alert('Required data\n' + text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are try dispay json data in view blade in laravel try to do this

`<php echo $data ?>`

or

`@php echo $data; @endphp` instead of `{{ $data }}`

Answer (score -1):

use decodeURI javascript function to show
example

```
var s= decodeURI('your string');
```

Comment: This is not a URI; `&quot;` is an HTML entity.