# Javascript find and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a small code generator for my team

It's very simple, you just fill out the fields & it effectively does a find and replace in the DIV below and shows what the new code should be. That's great!

The problem I have is that in order to get the code showing as clear text on the screen, I had to replace all the special characters with the below (e.g. &lt)

[image]

When manually copying and pasting, this is not a problem. However, I have a button that copies the contents of the DIV and exports to a .html file.

This then does not execute the code, because it copies the actual contents (including the lack of special characters).

Is there any way to get this code to run when I export? Is there a simple function to switch it back to be the original code before exporting?

The code generator is effectively lots of finds and replaces to enter user defined variables, it is below:

```
[code]function findMyText2(needle2, replacement2) {
 if (haystackText.length == 0) {
      haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
 }
 var match = new RegExp(needle2, "ig");     
 var replaced = "";
 if (replacement2.length > 0) {
      replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement2);
 }

 else {
      var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle2 + "</div>";
      replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
 }
 document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
 haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
```

The full code to be edited is:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please post the generator code to see what's missing?

Comment: i guess jQuery `text()` does escape html entyties…

Comment: Hi there, I've added the code there too. You can see it's very simple and does what I needed - I just don't know how to remove all those special characters. ----- Even a simple copy & paste code of the screen contents, rather than the backend code, would be ideal, but haven't been able to find anything yet

Comment: In fact, copying text from one div to the other (as is is printed on the screen - not the HTML itself) would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood of the problem, you basically need to unescape the contents of the div. Here is how you can do it.

HTML

```
<div style="display:none" id="dummy"></div>
```

JQuery

```
var decoded = $("#dummy").html(encoded).text();
```

This code sets the internal HTML of the "dummy" div as encoded, which makes  jquery decode it. Then text() simply returns the decoded code.

For more info see here - [Javascript decoding html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities)

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like exactly what I wanted to do. I've created a js file with your script in it (changing div name of course) and used a button to call decoded() on click - but it doesn't seem to do anything?