# Javascript replacing single quotes with &#39

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an MVC project and are passing a string to the view through the ViewData. The string has single quotes, double quotes and other special characters (to give some background, I am following the [store locator](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082510-1.aspx) tutorial as a test project, but using Razor instead of asp.net.)

As soon as the variable hits the Javascript tags, the special characters get decoded onto HTML. 
For example:

```
storeList =  [{ title: &#39;Location # 12&#39;, position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.85914441, -96.9444170)},{ title: &#39;Location # 7&#39;, position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.855526, -96.9555080)}]....
```

When it should contain:

```
storeList =  [{ title: 'Location # 12', position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.85914441, -96.9444170)},{ title: 'Location # 7', position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.855526, -96.9555080)}] ....
```

I have tried the solution listed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities) but have not been successful:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var storeList = $("<div/>").html(@ViewData["storeList"]).text();
```

But I get an error regardless:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &"
```

And the error starts at the &#39:

```
var storeList = $("<div/>").html([{ title: &#39;Location # 12&#39;, position: .....
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw` to skip the html escaping with Razor.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try `Html.Raw()` to insert the html unescaped.