# Why is v-html not rendering html

Tags: html, string, vue.js, urldecode

I am trying to render some html coming from an api. The v-html tag is outputting the `<p>` tags onto the page instead of treating them as html.

This is the data I am rendering:

```
Bio:"&lt;p&gt;Throughout his PhD and post-doctoral research, Dr David focussed on transdermal medical technology. While presenting his research at a skincare conference, he had his &quot;light-bulb moment&quot; realising the expertise he had developed could be reapplied to solve some of the major challenges facing the global cosmetic skincare industry. &lt;/p&gt;"
```

this is the html with the v-html

```
<div v-html="decodeURIComponent(teamMember.Bio)"></div>
```

I also tried

```
<div v-html="teamMember.Bio"></div>
```

and

```
<div v-html="decodeURI(teamMember.Bio)"></div>
```

but they all show the paragraph tags on the page instead of rendering.

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem and found the solution like below;

```
computed: {
        parsedHtml () {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const elem = parser.parseFromString(this.teamMember.Bio, 'text/html');

            return elem.body.innerText;
        }
    }
```