# Converting HTML special characters in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I am binding to a DropDownList as follows;

```
Sub bindGalleries(ByVal catID As Integer)
    ddlGalleries.DataSource = Galleries.GetGalleries(catID)
    ddlGalleries.DataTextField = "GalleryName"
    ddlGalleries.DataValueField = "GalleryID"
    ddlGalleries.DataBind()
End Sub
```

One of the items in the list is: 'Kültür & Sanat', which is displayed just right in the dropdownlist. But when I look at the source of the page, it is: `K&#252;lt&#252;r &amp; Sanat`

How can I get the source to be exactly the same as the original string?

Note: my meta tag is:  in master page..

Comment: i'm not positive, but won't it always display it as &amp; in the source no matter what you do

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you need:

```
Server.HtmlDecode("K&#252;lt&#252;r &amp; Sanat");
```

Write a method to "sanitize" the items in the DDL and store them in an array. Then just bind to the array.

You can populate the DDL in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use backslashes to escape

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see those characters is because those characters are being htmlencoded upon saving into your source.

i.e.

```
YourSource = server.htmlEncode(value)
```

or

```
YourSource = server.urlEncode
```

You can save it to its original form by using `server.htmlDecode` or by omitting the server.htmlEncode.

Comment: No, actually the values are saved just fine, when rendered to the page as html, they look fine too. But when I look at the source they are encoded.  I am getting the value with javascript and sending it to a http handler. By the time it reaches the handler, the characters are now little question marks in  diamond shapes. So somehow, either I need to decode them during binding? or how do I decode the diamond shapes when they reach to my ashx file?

Comment: Try using jquery to retrieve the value of the dropdown like the method shown in the link?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery

Comment: Do you know how can I prevent the page to be rendered like that in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the proper charset in the heading portion of your page.

Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16"/>
```

Comment: this didn't work. somehow, I need to prevent rendering of those special characters...