# why does this work to encode and decode HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a simple easy quick way to decode and encode a text.

The best I have found is this below.

1. Does it make any difference using `$("<div/>")` and why is it here even though there is not div?
2. Do you have any easier faster way to encode and decode HTML?

Code:

```
var myHTMLstring = "<p /> + <br /> sdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsfdsf";

var myEncoded = $('<div/>').text(myHTMLstring).html();
//&lt;p /&gt; + &lt;br /&gt; sdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsfdsf


var myDecoded = $('<div/>').html(myEncoded).text();
//<p /> + <br /> sdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsfdsf
```

Comment: What do you mean by en/decoding? You mean html entities?

Comment: Was solved also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery/

Comment: i know but i wanted to know why.. thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works because the jQuery `text` method uses `createTextNode()`, which replaces special characters with their HTML entity equivalents. You can fiddle with that method<sup>**1**</sup> to create an alternative, but if you use jQuery anyway, the method you use is nice and swift.

<sup>**1**</sup> this would be the plain javascript equivalent:

```
function encode(htmlstr){
   var x = document.createTextNode()
      ,y = document.createElement('div');;
   x.textContent = htmlstr;
   y.appendChild(x);
   return y.innerHTML;
}

function decode(htmlstr){
   var y = document.createElement('div');;
   y.innerHTML = htmlstr;
   return y.innerText || y.textContent;
}
```

or even in one go:

```
function htmlcode(htmlstr,doDecode){
   var x = document.createTextNode()
      ,y = document.createElement('div');;
   x.textContent = htmlstr;
   if (doDecode) { y.innerHTML = htmlstr; }
   else { y.appendChild(x); }
   return doDecode? (y.innerText || x.textContent) : y.innerHTML;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/kTWwq/)

Comment: wow great answer thanks - so  i'm creating a div in memory as a placeholder type of thing but its not ever being added to the page. it could have been a <p /> ?

Comment: If it's never added to the DOM, `<p />` should be fine, although I would always use `<p></p>` to avoid browser dependent errors later on.

Comment: so then should I also rather use the div like this -- $('<div></div>').text(myHTMLstring).html();

Comment: Yep. Well, it's not bad anyway. I remember from the gruesome IE-days completely embty pages, e.g. when using something like `<div/><script>...</script>` at the end of a page. On the other hand, I suppose `$('<div/>')` is solved the right way by jQuery - it was *designed* to solve cross browser problems.