# Add html tags in another html tags attribute with Asp.Net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want add html tags in another html tags attribute like:

```
<p title="<strong class="cssClass">bold</strong>">
some text
</p>
```

how i can do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? That's not how HTML works...

Comment: It does not work. If you want to format some content by jQuery, you have to use CSS. try something like `$('p').css('font-weight',' bold');`

Comment: jQuery? What do you need jQuery for? This is just CSS, no jQuery.

Comment: some of jquery plugins works like this and twitter bootstrap is like to this:
<p data-title="<strong class="cssClass">bold</strong>">
some text
</p>

Comment: i dont know WHY stackoverflow users which cannot answer question give to me vote Down,why?why?why?WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Only with encode:

```
<p title="@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<strong class=\"cssClass\">bold</strong>")"> 
some text 
</p>
```

but you receive:

```
&lt;strong class=&quot;cssClass&quot;&gt;bold&lt;/strong&gt;
```

Comment: i dont know WHY stackoverflow users which cannot answer question give to me vote Down,why?why?why?WHY?

i now blocked from stackoverflow because users without any cause gived to me vote Down.

Comment: @kia then you can use this to decode: [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

At the Browser, title has a default default behavior and you cannot change this on native way. If you want to format the Title property to do a stylish tooltip, you could use a jQuery plugin to do that. Check [this link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/). It shows lots of plugins to do this work.

Comment: i dont know WHY stackoverflow users which cannot answer question give to me vote Down,why?why?why?WHY? i now blocked from stackoverflow because users without any cause gived to me vote Down

Comment: I didn't vote you down @Kia. What part of my awser you don't understand?