# Append ajax HTML string to the DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script receives some data from a PHP page. One item called "content" contains HTML code. I have to put my HTML code in a div but unfortunately, it is appended as plain text. How can I append it to the DOM as real HTML? 
This is my jQuery code:

```
      $.ajax({
      'url': 'ajaxdashboard.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function (json) {
          $.each(json, function (key, value) {
              for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                  $('#arguments').append('<div class="well student" style="display: none;" id="post-' + value[i].id + '"><h3>' + value[i].title + '</h3><span>Published by <font color="blue"><b>' + value[i].name + ' ' + value[i].surname + '</b></font></span><br><br><span id="post-content-' + value[i].id + '"></span></div>');
                  $('#post-content-' + value[i].id).html(value[i].content);
                  $('#post-' + value[i].id).fadeIn();
              }
          });
      }
  });
```

Comment: This is a little ambiguous to me. Are you trying to display the returned content as HTML (i.e. the user will see the tags)? Or do you want to render the HTML?

Comment: I have to display as html, user should see the result in rendered html :) No tags at all!

Comment: The code looks okay to me. Are you using <pre> or <code> tags by any chance?

Comment: Is the problem with #arguments or #post-content ? Does value[i].content come back html encoded?

Comment: Is your html code is encoded means do it contains characters &lt; &gt; &#32, &nbsp; etc..

Comment: @flem I don't know if it's encoded, using console.log i see this as a sample content: &lt;p&gt;
 Hello!&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: That's you're problem. &lt; in html is <. Therefore that's what you see. Update your PHP to return the original HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is that the PHP is returning encoded html. < in html is <. Therefore that's what the user will see.

Update your PHP to return the original HTML. Otherwise you can cheat it with jQuery something like this:

```
$('#post-content-' + value[i].id).html($(value[i].content).text());
```

[Source for decoding html.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this.

use text() instead of html() that escapes automatically.

[Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

Comment: `text()` won't render html in DOM