# html entities in a javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, entities

I have a string coming from a XML (which I can't edit) and I'd like to print it trough an alert in javascript.

Example of my string:

```
This is &agrave; string
```

And I need to print in an alert:

```
This is à string
```

is there a js html decode?

Comment: You need to show a little code which demonstrates how this values makes its way from the XML into the JS.

Comment: I got it from XmlReader in C#

Comment: if you using jquery this question tells you how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var encoded = "This is &agrave; string";
var decoded = $("<div/>").html(encoded).text();
alert(decoded);
```

Comment: What this answer fails to mention is that, despite the question not being tagged with it, **you need the jQuery library to use this answer**. Without jQuery you'll be greeted with a lovely DOMException error.

Answer (score 14):

you could put the string in a dom element and read it out again, even without jquery:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700369/1986499

Edit by recent demand to include some code from another SO answer:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = encoded;
var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: Just because the question is a duplicate doesn't mean you should post a link-only answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just a *tiny* bit late, but just in case anyone else finds this via Google (like I did), I thought I'd improve upon [Imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1986499/imperative)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14937257/2283305).

```
function showbullet() {
  var tempelement = document.createElement('div');
  tempelement.innerHTML = "&bull;";
  alert("Here, have a bullet!\n" + tempelement.innerHTML);
}
showbullet();
```

I've tested this and confirmed it works in Chrome/43.0.2357.130 m; Firefox/32.0.1; Internet Explorer/9.0.8112.16421. There's no need to go mucking about with nodeValue's and what not; the entity will be replaced with it's associated character as soon as the assignment is complete. (Note, however, that doing `alert(tempelement.innerHTML="&bull;");` does **not** work in any of the browsers I tested!)