# Show Numeric Code Reference (NCR) in alert

Tags: javascript

Some characters in our database are stored in NCR (example `&#21488;` (台)).

I need to be able to show them in an `alert` window, so I need to translate the value to something that JavaScript can show.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937169/html-entities-in-a-javascript-alert, but I won't mark it as a duplicate because that question's answers are vague and/or require jQuery.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't really want to use jquery only for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) on just the numeric value.

> The static `String.fromCharCode()` method returns a string created by using the specified sequence of Unicode values.

First you'll need to strip the `&#`. We can do this with JavaScript's `replace()` method:

```
var symbol = "&#21488".replace("&#", "");
```

Then we can pass it into `String.fromCharCode()`:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(symbol));
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var symbol = "&#21488".replace("&#", "");
alert(String.fromCharCode(symbol));
```

---

## Update

> ...the only problem is that has mixed content. For example: "12 Amp. Street &#21488"
> – [Panos K.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344144/show-numeric-code-reference-ncr-in-alert/30344482?noredirect=1#comment48782383_30344482)

For this we can use a regular expression to match the symbol and replace it in-line.

```
var str = "12 Amp. Street &#21488";
```

For this I'm going to use the regular expression `/&#(\d*)/`, which matches the combination of "&#" followed by a group of any number of digits. Calling `replace()` as we did before, we can instead replace with a function which has two parameters: `match`, the entire match (`&#21488`) and `number`, the group of numbers (`21488`). From here we simply return `String.fromCharCode(number)`:

```
var replaced = str.replace(/&#(\d*)/g, function(match, number) {
    return String.fromCharCode(number);
});
```

`replaced` should now contain the value `"12 Amp. Street 台"`.

---

#### Demo

```js
var str = "12 Amp. Street &#21488";

var replaced = str.replace(/&#(\d*)/g, function(match, number) {
  return String.fromCharCode(number);
});

alert(replaced);
```

Comment: Thank you James, the only problem is that has mixed content. For example: "12 Amp. Street &#21488"