# php & javascript alert that contains a string with double quote

Tags: javascript, php, string, xss, quotes

This is an example of string that should I output in a javascript alert();

`string with "double quote" in it`

Because this string can be edited via PHP by my users it's better to prevent XSS attacks. To do so in the HTML of my document I usually do:

```
<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $MY_STRING, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) ); ?>
```

That works great.

But now I just noticed that if I output the same string in a javascript alert:

```
<script>
alert( "<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $MY_STRING, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) ); ?>" );
</script>
```

The output of the alert in this case is:

`string with &quot;double quote&quot; in it`

What is the best way to output the double quotes in a alert, but also preventig XSS injection?

Comment: `addslashes(strip_tags( ... ))` *should* do the job...

Comment: You could put it in a div before alerting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14937257/1921862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ENT_NOQUOTES` flag ensures all quotes ' and " are not escaped and the `addslashes` escapes them for the js alert function.

```
$string = 'string<< with "double quote" in it';
echo htmlentities(addslashes($string), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Output:

```
string&lt;&lt; with \"double quote\" in it
```

Keeps your quotes and escapes malicious html tags

Comment: It's a non readable output. the author probably wants:  with "double quote" in it: as an output

Comment: @FranklinRivero  Well then he could use ```addcslashes``` instead of ```addslashes```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( "<?php echo( addslashes( $MY_STRING ) ); ?>" );
```

Use `addslashes()` rahter than `htmlspecialchars()` or combine both. Hope it helps.

`addslashes()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside alert is treated like a string and won't be executed, so you won't get an XSS attack if you just make sure it's a singlestring by just escaping the "

For an alert you don't need to use htmlspecialchars, you can just do it like this:

```
<script>
    alert( "<?php echo addslashes($MY_STRING);  ?>" );
 </script>
```

Comment: unless the string is something like: `"); document.location('http://somekinkypornsitewithdonkeys.com'); //`

Comment: Glad you edited the answer to put in `addslashes` ;)

Comment: Yeah, work in progress, writing and testing. BTW I tested it and it works, no XSS there, remove down vote?.