# How to print UTF-8 Symbols using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to print triangular image using javascript. Using HTML it will come like this

All Coupons & Deals ▼

Using JavaScript I did not get an any output

```
textContent="All Coupons & Deals &#9660;  ";
```

Comment: `textContent = "All Coupons & Deals ▼";`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937169/html-entities-in-a-javascript-alert

Comment: @PedroLobito Er... Not dupe of it. `:)`

Comment: I never said it was a dupe

Comment: @PedroLobito You got me there. Not fair... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Either use `innerHTML` (coz that's not a text):**

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="All Coupons & Deals &#9660;";
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Or try it with the Unicode:

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").textContent = "All Coupons & Deals ▼";
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```