# Decode HTML entities with Regex

Tags: jquery, html, regex, html-entities, html-encode

I've a large amount of encoded text, like this:

```
&#60;div id&#61;&#34;readingPaneContentContainer&#34; class&#61;&#34;ClearBoth&#34;  cmp&#61;&#34;cmp&#34; ulr&#61;&#34;ulr&#34;&#62;&#60;a id&#61;&#34;rpFocusElt&#34; href&#61;&#34;javascript&#58;void&#40;0&#41;&#59;&#34; style&#61;&#34;height&#58;1px&#59;width&#58;1px&#59
```

I would like de-encode all, so to have (Example):

```
<div id="readingPaneContentContainer" class="ClearBoth".....
```

Is possible to do with Regular Expressions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Luca

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: jQuery, but i think that will don't change anything..correct?

Comment: regex implementation is different in different languages. Also it makes a difference to how one repesents the entites in unicode.

Comment: Possibly of interest - [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/427192)

Comment: @DanPichelman : This regex wouldn't replace encoded tags but match only existent (Not encoded).

Comment: Why do you want to use Regex? Wouldn't it be faster to create a small dictionary mapping encodings to decodings and just loop over the string, replacing things as you go?

Comment: @Luca the language is called JavaScript. jQuery is a library built on this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread - it has your solution for jQuery that works perfectly:

[How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

```
var encoded = '&#60;div id&#61;&#34;readingPaneContentContainer&#34; class&#61;&#34;ClearBoth&#34;  cmp&#61;&#34;cmp&#34; ulr&#61;&#34;ulr&#34;&#62;&#60;a id&#61;&#34;rpFocusElt&#34; href&#61;&#34;javascript&#58;void&#40;0&#41;&#59;&#34; style&#61;&#34;height&#58;1px&#59;width&#58;1px&#59';

var decoded = $("<div/>").html(encoded).text();
```

Does not use regex.

Comment: Works fine, but to maintain the tag must be removed .text()  Thanks you

Comment: This is really slow compared to regexp

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
var regex = /&#(\d{2});/g;
var match;
while(match = regex.exec(myString)) {
    match = match[1];
    myString = myString.substring(0, regex.lastIndex - 5) + convert[match] + myString.substring(regex.lastIndex);
}
```

might work but there must be better solutions (considering convert is an object that makes the conversion, eg 80: '<').

Explaination: regex.exec with a 'global' flag allows looping through the regex, regex.lastPoint's value being the pointer to the rest of the string (not being tested yet).

**Edit:**
Working.

Comment: Sorry parenthesis error in the regex, I changed it, maybe try again (I'll run some tests myself).

Comment: Now i get the following error: convert is not defined                 Thanks you for the help ;)

Comment: Quote: *(considering convert is an object that makes the conversion, eg 80: '<')* You have to build this map before doing it. Anyway doing it with jQuery is a safer and easier way.