# characters in json response breaks jquery text()

Tags: jquery

I'm receiving various strings from an api using . I have been stripping the html from these strings as follows:

```
var comb = $(qu1[i].title + qu1[i].content).text()
```

I have encountered a problem with strings like this: `San Diego Zoo&#39;s Animal Bytes:`, which returns a syntax error. I'm not sure why jquery is having a problem with this string.

Any idea how I can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is not a selector, and newer versions of jQuery (1.9+) no longer parse html strings that do not start with `<`. Try:

```
var comb = $('<div>').append($.parseHTML(qu1[i].title + qu1[i].content)).text();
```

[`$.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) is available in jQuery 1.8+ and helps preventing XSS (this does not strip all JS, only script tags. `onevent` attributes are kept). Though, if the source is trustworthy you can append the html directly. I prefer to be on the safer side. `=]`

Basically, the code creates an element (`div`) on the fly and appends the cleanly parsed markup then retrieves its text presentation. I can't claim originality though, similar approaches are shown at [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419664/1331430) and many other threads.

As no references are kept to the `div` element nor its wrapper jQuery object, these will be collected by the GC very fast.

Reference:

[jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide - `jQuery(htmlString)` versus `jQuery(selectorString)`](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring)

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as the system lets me (another 9 minutes :-) )

Comment: No hurries, had some additions to make anyway. `=]`

Comment: could also do it this way: `$('<div>'+qu1[i].title + qu1[i].content+'</div>').text()`

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, though then you can't use `$.parseHTML` which returns DOM nodes. `=]` Also, I believe that could affect how malformed html would be parsed, though this should be off-topic.