# How do you find the (string) length of a starting tag or ending tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to write a jQuery or pure Javascript function (preferring the more readable solution) that can count the length of a starting tag or ending tag in an HTML document.

For example,

```
<p>Hello.</p>
```

would return 3 and 4 for the starting and ending tag lengths. Adding attributes,

```
<span class="red">Warning!</span>
```

would return 18 and 7 for the starting and ending tag lengths. Finally,

```
<img src="foobar.png"/>
```

would return 23 and 0 (or -1) for the starting and ending tag lengths.

I'm looking for a canonical, guaranteed-to-work-according-to-spec solution, so I'm trying to use DOM methods rather than manual text manipulations. For example, I would like the solution to work even for weird cases like

```
<p>spaces infiltrating the ending tag</ p >
```

and

```
<img alt="unended singleton tags" src="foobar.png">
```

and such. That is, my hope is that as long as we use proper DOM methods, we should be able to find the number of characters between `<` and `>` no matter how weird things get, even

```
<div data-tag="<div>">HTML-like strings within attributes</div>
```

I have looked at the jQuery API (especially the Manipulation section, including DOM Insertion and General Attributes subsections), but I don't see anything that would help.

Currently the best idea I have, given an element `node` is

```
lengthOfEndTag = node.tagName.length + 3;

lengthOfStartTag = node.outerHTML.length
                 - node.innerHTML.length
                 - lengthOfEndTag;
```

but of course I don't want to make such an assumption for the end tag.

(Finally, I'm familiar with regular expressions—but trying to avoid them if at all possible.)

---

**EDIT**

@Pointy and @squint helped me understand that it's not possible to see `</ p >`, for example, because the HTML is discarded once the DOM is created. That's fine. The objective, adjusted, is to find the length of the start and end tags *as would be rendered in `outerHTML`*.

Comment: The browser isn't really under any obligation to record and expose the source code details of HTML tags as they appeared when parsed.

Comment: @Pointy - I don't disagree; but yet the browser does expose things like `outerHTML` and `innerHTML`; so I feel there could yet be a way to do what I'm seeking...

Comment: After your page loads, the original HTML markup is gone. Closest you can do is ask the browser to read the DOM and render what it observes to a new HTML string.

Comment: @squint - Hm, okay, then let's say I'm speaking not about "raw, as-is HTML," but the HTML that `outerHTML` provides. That'd be good enough. (I'll edit my question.)

Comment: @BoltClock's comment disappeared, but, let's assume valid markup for now.

Comment: @acheong87: Using `.outerHTML`, try `var m = foo.outerHTML; var res = m.slice(0, m.indexOf(">") + 1);`

Comment: ...oops, didn't read all the details in your question ...attribute values with `>` and so on.

Comment: Note also that not all tags will have closing tags (`<input>`, `<br>`).

Comment: @Pointy - Yes, I mentioned singleton tags in my question, with examples.

Comment: ...to resolve the attribute issue, you could try iterating the `.attributes` object, and building the string manually with attribute names and values *(plus tag name, spaces, brackets, etc)*. but consider that boolean attributes can take many forms. `selected` and `selected="selected"` are equivalent, so you'll never know which was originally sent.

Comment: ...another possibility is to make an XHR request for the same page. Assuming the output is static, you could take the markup and attempt some nasty string analysis, or just use a JavaScript based HTML parser.

Comment: can you elaborate a situation where it will need?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to do this?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SusheelMishra - I was trying to answer this question by another user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359314/how-do-i-find-the-string-index-of-a-tag-an-element-without-counting-expanded-e/16360608#16360608, who's trying to detect the starting and ending indices of a text selection by the user, _without counting expanded HTML entities_.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - See above. (Can only tag one user per comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2292532/925913) helped me understand what @Pointy and @squint were trying to say.

The following solution works for me:

```
$.fn.lengthOfStartTag = function () {
    var node = this[0];
    if (!node || node.nodeType != 1) {
        $.error("Called $.fn.lengthOfStartTag on non-element node.");
    }
    if (!$(node).is(":empty")) {
        return node.outerHTML.indexOf(node.innerHTML);
    }
    return node.outerHTML.length;
}

$.fn.lengthOfEndTag = function () {
    var node = this[0];
    if (!node || node.nodeType != 1) {
        $.error("Called $.fn.lengthOfEndTag on non-element node.");
    }
    if (!$(node).is(":empty")) {
        var indexOfInnerHTML = node.outerHTML.indexOf(node.innerHTML);
        return node.outerHTML.length - (indexOfInnerHTML + node.innerHTML.length);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[Sample jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acheong87/NB4H3/)

Comment: You seem to be using `is(":empty")` to determine if a tag is self closing.  This isn't a good test as `<div></div>` is also empty.

Comment: Just be aware that the tags will not count extra white spaces.

Comment: @DMoses - Yes, I realized that that part of my requirement was too crazy, and unnecessary anyway. Thanks for the caution though.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Oh, you're right. `$('<img>').get(0).outerHTML` returns `<img>`, `<img/>` returns `<img>` as well, `<div>` returns `<div></div>`. I think the only workaround for this might be to actually use a list of singleton tags, _e.g._ `area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param`. For now I'll just leave it a caveat in my answer. Thanks for the alert.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - No, wait, actually, I think it's fine as it is. In any case that an element is "empty", the length of the `outerHTML` is returned. That's all I really want, in the end. Appreciate the input regardless.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to do this could be to use *XMLSerializer's* `serializeToString` on a clone copy of the node (with *id* set) to avoid having to parse *innerHTML*, then split over `"><"`

```
var tags = (function () {
    var x = new XMLSerializer(); // scope this so it doesn't need to be remade
    return function tags(elm) {
        var s, a, id, n, o = {open: null, close: null}; // spell stuff with var
        if (elm.nodeType !== 1) throw new TypeError('Expected HTMLElement');
        n = elm.cloneNode(); // clone to get rid of innerHTML
        id = elm.getAttribute('id'); // re-apply id for clone
        if (id !== null) n.setAttribute('id', id); // if it was set
        s = x.serializeToString(n); // serialise
        a = s.split('><');
        if (a.length > 1) { // has close tag
            o.close = '<' + a.pop();
            o.open = a.join('><') + '>'; // join "just in case"
        }
        else o.open = a[0]; // no close tag
        return o;
    }
}()); // self invoke to init
```

After running this, you can access `.length` of *open* and *close* properties

```
tags(document.body); // {open: "<body class="question-page">", close: "</body>"}
```

What if an attribute's value has `><` in it? *XMLSerializer* escapes this to `&gt;&lt;` so it won't change the `.split`.
What about no close tag? *close* will be `null`.