# encoding/decoding html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, encoding

I am using Tinymce editor for formatting articles in my ASP.NET page.
here is my code:-

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textarea" Height="70px" 
        Width="324px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Button" 
    OnClientClick="encodeMyHtml()" onclick="submit_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
</div>
```

and this is what i have find on the web for encoding html [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1555681/5450334.aspx/1?p=True&t=635091898694790976) and tried to use it.

```
function encodeMyHtml() {
    var htmlToEncode = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    // save content after encoding
    alert(htmlToEncode);
    var encodedHtml = escape(htmlToEncode);
    alert(encodedHtml);
    // Later when displaying it back, decode it.
    var ohtml = unescape(encodedHtml);
    alert(ohtml);
}
```

and this also

```
   function encodeMyHtml() {
      var htmlText = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
      htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\</g, "&lt;");
      //alert("hello2");
      htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\>/g, "&gt;");
      alert(htmlText);
 }
```

but it's not working for me and it doesn't even display htmlToEncode value  in alert() function. Everytime I click submit button, it display the following error

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client and etc..

Please help to figure out the Problem. I want to encode the HTML content and then store it into the database and then to retrieve it on another page.

Comment: Not answering your question, but I think generally we should store text in database as-is. Encode the text only when necessary (e.g. to display).

Comment: but asp.net doesnot allow to store html markup in database, that's why it's necessary to encode.

Comment: [Check This Link. This question has been asked so many times.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery

Comment: The second one you are using `document.createElement` not `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Please check this link. this was asked so many times.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: @hereblur: oops, that was by mistake,sorry for that. But I have also tried "getElementById('<%= textarea.ClientID %>').value;", it's also not working.

Comment: @Raghubar: both of the links show decoding part, but my code fails to get the content of **textarea** for encoding. What to do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

// temporary element has all the native encoding capability you need
var p = document.createElement('p');

// set text and get back HTML
p.appendChild( document.createTextNode(text) );
var html = p.innerHTML;

// add line breaks to display in elements that don't preformat (like textarea does)
html = html.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '<br />' );

// set html and get back text
p.innerHTML = html;
text = p.textContent||p.innerText;
```

Comment: I am sorry, by mistake I place createElement over there, and corrected it. I am trying to retrieve the content of existing **textarea** and then trying to encode html part, but unable to do it.

Comment: It fails to get value from the **textarea**. I tried this 
`var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        alert(text);`
and the alert() pop-up window doesn't display anything.

Comment: good point. simply encoding won't create `<br>` elements. will update

Comment: does your textarea really have the id attribute of 'textarea'?

Comment: your problem getting the value of the textarea form element is a side issue to your encoding question. Once you've solved it, you'll find that the encoding code I've provided works.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE editor already encode tags written by user.

To decode those tags, you can use the following line

```
    var decodedHtml = $('<div/>').html(yourText).text();
```

Comment: I think it doesn't. When I submit text under TinyMCE editor to database, .net framework stops the processing of website and give an XSS error.