# what would be the best way to encode variable for url ? in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, encode

I am making a bookmarklet that uses `$.getJSON()` to transfer data from browser (different domain) to server and back. and I am having several issues with url encoding.

When I send the data to php I use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()`  the response. in the php i do no encoding or decoding.

In many situation this works fine in cases of "/ & etc.

However if i have ',' or % or some other character, when i get the response and it tries to `decodeURIComponent`. i get the following error :URIError: malformed URI sequence

Is there a better way to encode url ?

Thanks

Comment: was all `,` doesn't been converted into `%2C`

Comment: that's really weird. in some places it works in others i doesnt. in some languges it does in others it doesnt

Comment: its really best to encode your URL using PHP because if you let javascript encode it for you it different kinds of browsers `decodeURIcomponent` maybe behaves differently

Comment: And how will i decode it afterward in the JS ? + will php be able to pick up the un-encoded url ?

Comment: I've gone through the code again  and found out that i was encoding both in JS and in php, but decoding just in JS, so fixing this fixed most of the issues except quotes " instead of decoding it its writes :&quot;

Comment: I know this is a very dirty trick but if its only ',' is being the problem, why not replace is with the right encoding using string functions?

Comment: seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery fixed the issues

Comment: well its really unsafe... I think...

Comment: Check the above solution provided in that question ,its dreamy . fixed everything !