# vanilla js alternative to jquery method to perform safe html decode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-encode

I've got a single dependency on jQuery that I don't want, and need a browser-safe method to decode server-side html encoded content.

The effect I'm going for is to replace an existing DOM element with the the html that gets decoded, along the following lines:

```
$('#targetId').replaceWith($('<div/>').html(value).text());
```

where `value` contains an html-encoded string.

Alternatively, an more direct approach would also be welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

Comment: @kapa - not a duplicate. OP is asking to do this without jquery.

Comment: @mayabelle Yeah, did not notice. Sorry. In this case: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/unescape-html-in-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
function DecodeHtmlString(htmlString){
  var temp = document.createElement("textarea");
  temp.innerHTML = htmlString;
  return temp.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Real world alternative. I mix some PHP because reasons.

```js
var Lang = Lang || new Object();

Lang._t  = function(str) {
    var buf = [];

    for (var i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
    }

    return buf.join('');
},


Lang.same_password = Lang._t(<?php echo json_encode($langtextos->same_password); ?>);


function foo(pass1, pass2){
   if( pass1 == pass2){
       message.innerHTML = Lang.same_pass;
       return false;
   }
      
   return true;
}
```