# Using JS - jQuery, how can I unescape html and put `quotes & <>` back in the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

Essentially I want to undo the escapeHTML() function I found [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript), after I used it.

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }

function unescapeHtml(safe) {
    return safe
         .replace("&amp;", /&/g)
         .replace("&lt;", /</g)
         .replace( "&gt;", />/g)
         .replace("&quot;", /"/g)
         .replace("&#039;", /'/g);
 }


var a = escapeHtml("<div> yo & yo squirrl's </div>");
var b = unescapeHtml(a);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);//should log "<div> yo & yo squirrl's </div>"
```

I tried the obvious but no deal. http://jsfiddle.net/ej6bX/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use

```
function unescapeHtml(safe) {
    return safe.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}
```

---

A more clear approach using jQuery could be

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return $('<div />').text(unsafe).html()
}

function unescapeHtml(safe) {
    return $('<div />').html(safe).text();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EhhVh/)

Comment: That jQuery solution is pretty amazing.  What is `('<div />')` for exactly? Oh I think i understand.  In the situation where the string was `<p> yo & yo squirrl's <p>` it would no longer work though?

Comment: @Squirrl we creates a temporary div element using `$('<div />')` then assigns the given value as text to it so that it will render the given text after doing an html escape then we reads the parsed html content which will give us the escaped string - the reverse for unescape

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery#comment6018122_2419664, your second `unescapeHtml` is *not* secure, and can lead to XSS attacks.

Comment: If you have a lot of calls to unescape function, then it can hurt performance - when using this approach: $('<div />')

Comment: Just an improvement - instead of `/&#039;/g`, use `/&#0*39;/g` - because `&#39;`, `&#039;` (or in fact `&#0039;` or `&#00000039;` etc.) all results in the same single quote. We do not know if the original encoder added any zeros or not.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** should be string not regular expression

```
function unescapeHtml(safe) {
    return safe
         .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
         .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
         .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
         .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
         .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
 }
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ej6bX/16/)</kbd>

Comment: I appreciate it, but yours is not getting rid of the 2nd `&lt &gt` sign

Comment: Isn't single quote `&#39;`, not `&#039;`