# Appending html in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying to edit a Wordpress plugin that uses JavaScript. I want to have HTML in the description field, but currently the JavaScript is outputting text, not translating it to HTML.

For instance, when the description is

> `Test <p>html</p>`

It prints it with the `<p>`, instead of rendering a new paragraph.

```
function appendPersonality(quiz, personality, hasTitle, hasImage, hasDescription) {
  var $personality, $title, $description, $image;

  $title = createIf(hasTitle, '<h2>', { 'html': personality.name });

  if (personality.image.file) {
    $image = createIf(hasImage, '<img>', {
      'class': classes('result-image'),
      'src': _getPath(personality.image.file.path),
      'alt': personality.image.alt
    });
  }

  $description = createIf(hasDescription, '<p>', {
    'html': personality.description
  });

  // NOTE (Emil): We only create $personality element if it has at least
  // one child element.
  if (hasTitle || hasImage || hasDescription) {
    $personality = $('<div>', { 'class': classes('personality') });

    $personality.append($title);
    $personality.append($image);
    $personality.append($description);
  }

  quiz.$resultWrapper.append($personality);

  setInlineImageHeight($image, $personality, quiz.$resultWrapper);

  return $personality;
}
```

Why does `'html': personality.description` not render html?

Comment: Need more details on where `$description` being used afterwards

Comment: Are we going to guess the structure of object?

Comment: @aahung I added the rest of the function. The full code I'm trying to edit is https://github.com/LumeniaAS/h5p-personality-quiz

Comment: @LaraBelle sorry, I thought this was just a quick JavaScript problem...I added the rest of the function, and this is the full code (https://github.com/LumeniaAS/h5p-personality-quiz)

Answer (score 0):

I took at the codes you posted, it should be fine. But my suggestion is to check the value of `personality.description`, it might be escaped at some point. you can unescape it using

(The function `unescapeHTML` is taken from [Arun P Johny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22279245/2361752))

```
function unescapeHtml(safe) {
    return safe.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}

...

$description = createIf(hasDescription, '<p>', {
  'html': unescapeHtml(personality.description)
});
```

Comment: It might be escaped at some point? Just like, arbitrarily excaped?  I don't see anywhere on the github https://github.com/LumeniaAS/h5p-personality-quiz where it is escaped

Comment: @jonbon Unless you can provide a full website/webpage or a live demo, as far as I know the repository only contains couple of files. Where did you assign the value `Test <p>html</p>` and can you check `params.resultScreen.displayDescription` is still `Test <p>html</p>`?

Comment: The test value is inputted through the plug-in interface

Comment: @jonbon then the "escape" should be conducted before the value being passed to you.