# HTML entities from json result into input field

Tags: javascript, php, json

From my API I get a json object with data. The special data is converted to HTML entities (using htmlspecialchars). Looks like this:

```
    {
        id: "0",
        title: "Hello &amp; good day",
    }
```

However, when i fetch the data using $.getJSON, and insert the data into the input value, the `&amp;` is still there.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: it seems duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery

Comment: True - thanks - haven't found this before now.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dummy element to pass the HTML entity in as the dummy element's `html`, then pass the `text()` of that dummy element to the `input` element's value:

```
var $dummy = $('<div/>', { html: 'Hello &amp; good day'});
$('input').val($dummy.text());
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/77ZmR/4).

In one line:

```
$('input').val($('<div/>', { html: 'Hello &amp; good day'}).text());
```

Comment: I like. Would there be a way to do this with the whole response? The response from json: `$.getJSON(.., function(response) {` As there will be multiple fields which needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the PHP to encode the text using [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode), you can decode the string before setting it as the input value using:

```
input.value = decodeURIComponent(jsonData.title);
```

(assuming that `jsonData.title` is the encoded string from the response.

Comment: Well, I can change the PHP code. But, thinking an extra time, should i just use htmlspecialchars_decode on the output then? Before the javascript recieves the data? Is it even needed to convert to entities on json results? Hm.

Comment: If you're sending the content with `json_encode` in your PHP, that will already be escaping quotes for you - so you may not need to.